# Почему в $__POST NULL?

Tags: javascript, php

В общем отправляю форму при помощи fetch, но в php в глобальном массиве _POST получается NULL

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$errors[] = $name;
$errors[] = $password;
$errors[] = $email;

echo json_encode($errors);
```

```js
sendForm(formSelector, url) {  
    const form = document.querySelector(formSelector);
    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: formData
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: саму форму покажите - html.  И еще вы отправляете FormData с заголовками json

Comment: `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` используйте и будет $_POST, или, как выше написали, считывайте php://input